# php file not shows error

Tags: php, wamp

I have PHP file inside the wamp server. when i run that file in localhost it gives some error like below.

This is My PHP file:

```
<?php
$response = array({
    "success": [
        {
            "message": "Required field id missing"
        },
        {
            "message": "successfully created."
        },
        {
            "message": "Oops! An error occured"
        }
    ]}
);
 
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['price']) && isset($_POST['description'])) {
 
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
 

    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
 
    
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();
 
   
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products(name, price, description) VALUES('$name', '$price', '$description')");
 
   
    if ($result) {
        
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";
 
       
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
      
        $response["success"] = 2;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";
 
    
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
   
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";
 
    
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

when i run it in localhost following error shows,

> ( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ')' in
>   D:\wamp\www\android\create_product.php on line 2

also suggest me that how to set the localpath to run php file in the browser.

Comment: i guess you are mixin PHP and JS..!

Comment: yes. any problem with the use of that?

Comment: Your queries are in risk for SQL Injection. BTW, you don't need to declare $response array in the top

Comment: where you have seen this format of array. this is the format of json.

Answer (score 1):

your array format is wrong, btw, **you dont need it**, because you are adding message to array in conditions, so just remove this part:

```
$response = array({
    "success": [
        {
            "message": "Required field id missing"
        },
        {
            "message": "successfully created."
        },
        {
            "message": "Oops! An error occured"
        }
    ]}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code better look this:

- You should not echo response after every conditional statement ends, you can do it once.
- Also when using `isset` function, you can as many params as you want.

```
 isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['price']) && isset($_POST['description'])
```

is equal to:

```
 isset($_POST['name'],$_POST['price'],$_POST['description'])
```

**Final:**

```
if (isset($_POST['name'],$_POST['price'],$_POST['description'])) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];


    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';


    $db = new DB_CONNECT();


    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO products(name, price, description) VALUES('$name', '$price', '$description')");


    if ($result) {
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";
    } else {
        $response["success"] = 2;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";
    }
} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";
}

echo json_encode($response);
```